# Регулярные выражения(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите в чем разница.

```js
function autoTags (str,tags, url){
 tags = '('+tags.join('|')+')';  
 return str.replace( new RegExp(tags,'gi'),`<a href="${url}$1">@$1</a>`);
};
const url = 'https://mysite.local/';
console.log(autoTags('I learning js',['JS','C#'],url));
```

Данный код отработает. 
Но если немного изменить вторую строчку(убрать круглые скобки, то уже подстановка не сработает):

```js
function autoTags (str,tags, url){
 tags = tags.join('|');  
 return str.replace( new RegExp(tags,'gi'),`<a href="${url}$1">@$1</a>`);
};
const url = 'https://mysite.local/';
console.log(autoTags('I learning js',['JS','C#'],url));
```

В чем магия? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Магия в том, что `/(abc|def)/gi` и `/abc|def/gi` - это разные регулярные выражения.

Comment: Точно.....не туда смотрел.
Я смотрел на результат tags т.е. tags = "(JS|C#)";
А необходимо было смотреть как вы написали /(abc|def)/gi   т.е. под другим углом как регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Круглые скобки задают так называемые *захватывающие подмаски* (или группы). Чтобы получить значение таких подмасок в шаблонах замены используются *обратные ссылки*. В JavaScrpipt они имеют форму `$n`, где `n` — это номер подмаски (отсчёт начинается с 1).

Если соответствующая подмаска отстутствует, обратная ссылка трактуется как буквальный текст.

В вашем случае подмаски не нужны, можно воспользоваться обратной ссылкой на целое совпадение, `$&`, см. [документацию по `String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description):

> `$&`   Вставляет сопоставившуюся подстроку.

```js
function autoTags (str,tags, url){
 tags = tags.join('|');  
 return str.replace( new RegExp(tags,'gi'),`<a href="${url}$&">@$&</a>`);
};
const url = 'https://mysite.local/';
console.log(autoTags('I learning js',['JS','C#'],url));
```

Comment: Благодарю! Не внимателен. Буду разбираться.